# how to install bitcoin from downloaded static binary

Tags: software-installation, bitcoin

due to the openssl problems my bitcoin is affected by the bug and i need to install using the statically linked bitcoin core from the binary on the bitcoin site.
I downloaded the program and extracted the files but I don't know what to do with them.
Can someone please walk me through where to move the files?
Also, how do I start the bitcoin program from this downloaded version?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! You might find assistance on this topic at https://bitcointalk.org